# Substr - Can't use value return in parse context

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to create an IF function with two conditions however, I am getting parse error "can't use value return in parse context". Any ideas please?

```
    $youlink = get_field('fl_tube');               
    if (strlen ($youlink) < 50 && substr($youlink, 0, 23) = "https://www.youtube.com"; ) {
some code here...    
    }
```

Comment: You're missing a `=` in your second condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have used the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `==`. There is also an added `;` after the string `https://www.youtube.com` which is a syntax error.

try the following code:

```
$youlink = get_field('fl_tube');               
if (strlen ($youlink) < 50 && substr($youlink, 0, 23) == "https://www.youtube.com" ) {
    some code here...    
}
```

Hope this helps.